# How can i replace a char in a String using chars from another string (Caesar Cypher)(JAVA)

Tags: java, string, char, caesar-cipher

I'm doing a `caesar-cypher`. Trying to replace all characters from a string to a certain character from the shifted alphabet.

Here is my code so far

```
   public static String caesarify(String str, int key){
    String alphabetNormal = shiftAlphabet(0);
    String alphabetShifted = shiftAlphabet(key);
    for (int i =0; i < str.length();i++){
        for (int c =0; c < alphabetNormal.length(); c++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == alphabetNormal.charAt(c)) {
                char replacement = alphabetShifted.charAt(c);
                str.replace(str.charAt(i), replacement);
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public static String shiftAlphabet(int shift) {
    int start =0;
    if (shift < 0) {
        start = (int) 'Z' + shift + 1;
    } else {
        start = 'A' + shift;
    }
    String result = "";
    char currChar = (char) start;
    for(; currChar <= 'Z'; ++currChar) {
        result = result + currChar;
    }
    if(result.length() < 26) {
        for(currChar = 'A'; result.length() < 26; ++currChar) {
            result = result + currChar;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't know why the string for example "ILIKEDONUTS" doesn't change to "JMJLFEPOVUT" when it's `caesarified`.

Comment: "cypher is a graph query language for Neo4j".  Don't use the "cypher" tag for a general cipher problem.  I've removed the tag.

Comment: In order to help you it would be helpful if we knew what the actual output *is* and not only what it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `replace()`, or any `replace` method, to replace a character at a given index in a `String`.  It doesn't work.  You're hoping that

```
str.replace(str.charAt(i), replacement);
```

will replace the `i`'th character of `str`.  As pointed out in the other (now deleted) answer, `str.replace` doesn't change `str` itself, so you'd need to write

```
str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), replacement);
```

*But that doesn't work.*  The `replace()` method doesn't know what your index `i` is.  It only knows what character to replace.  And, as the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) for `replace()` says, it replaces *all* characters in the string.  So suppose that `str.charAt(i)` is `'a'`, and you want to replace it with `'d'`.  This code would replace *all* `a` characters with `d`, including (1) those that you already replaced with `a` earlier in the loop, so that this will defeat the work you've already done; and (2) `a` characters that come after this one, which you want to replace with `d`, but this will fail because later in the loop you will see `d` and replace it with `g`.

So you can't use `replace()`.  There are a number of ways to replace the `i`'th character of a string, including using `substring()`:

```
str = str.substring(0, i) + replacement + str.substring(i + 1);
```

But there are better ways, if you are going to replace every character.  One is to create a `StringBuilder` from `str`, use `StringBuilder`'s `setCharAt` method to change characters at specified indexes, and then convert the `StringBuilder` back to a `String` at the end.  You should be able to look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to find out what methods to use.

**More:** After looking into this more, I see why it was returning all A's.  This inner loop has an error:

```
    for (int c =0; c < alphabetNormal.length(); c++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == alphabetNormal.charAt(c)) {
            char replacement = alphabetShifted.charAt(c);
            str.replace(str.charAt(i), replacement);
        }
    }
```

Suppose `key` is 1, and the current character is 'C'.  Your inner loop will eventually find `C` in `alphabetNormal`; it finds the corresponding character in `alphabetShifted`, which is `D`, and replaces `C` with `D`.

*But then it loops back.*  Since the next character in `alphabetNormal` is `D`, it now matches the *new* `str.char(i)`, which is now `D`, and therefore changes it again, to `E`.  Then it loops back, and ... you get the picture.

Comment: ajb thanks so much for your help, i haven't learned about StringBuilder yet, but i'll try to read more about it so i can understand more your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace below line 

str.replace(str.charAt(i), replacement);

With

  str= str.replace(str.charAt(i), replacement);

or you can make a String arr and then replace character in that. in the end create a new string from that array and return.

a better version of  caesarify():



public static String caesarify(String str, int key){
    String alphabetNormal = shiftAlphabet(0);
    String alphabetShifted = shiftAlphabet(key);
    //create a char array 
   char[] arr=str.toCharArray();
   //always try to create variable outside of loop  
  char replacement
    for (int i =0; i < arr.length();i++){
        for (int c =0; c < alphabetNormal.length(); c++) {

            if (arr[i] == alphabetNormal.charAt(c)) {
                replacement = alphabetShifted.charAt(c);
               //replace char on specific position in the array
               arr[i]= replacement;
            }
        }
    }
    //return arrray as String
    return new String(arr);
}
```